# AVD folder missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I want to add Virtual Device to Android Studio, but I've got this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: /home/kwarc/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_22.ini (Brak dostępu)
```

I found solutions saying that AVD folder will be in /root/.android/, but that's not true, there is only 'cache' folder In /home/kwarc/.android/ I have only these:

```
 -rw------- 1 root root 1704 lip 20 18:04 adbkey
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  711 lip 20 18:04 adbkey.pub
```

Comment: What steps did you perform that gave this error message?

Comment: @user3050423 This should be easy if you wish to use an existing emulator a few questions I assume the base API is 22 I have had issues with Nexus 4 so you might try Nexus 5X and do you get the step where you can select the AVD name

Comment: It's happening when I'm creating new virtual device. Whatever I will choose, it will fail, because there is no avd folder :/ I can download new image, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What solved for me
You can just create avd Folder inside .android and give permission

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to launch a virtual device which no longer exists on your machine. You should delete it and create a new one.

Comment: It's odd, but not... this is happening when I'm creating new AVD.

Comment: @user3050423 How do you create a new AVD? What steps are you following? Please edit your original question to give a step-by-step description of what you do.